# Cisco ASDM Remote Code Execution VULN

Tags: cisco-asa

Our Cisco ASA Devices (ASA 5515 Security Plus)
have been flagged for CVE-2021-1585 bug with high priority. I could not yet find any sources to resolve this issue.
Anyone here know how to fix?
The CVE literally says no workaround for this.

Below is the info that we have for our ASA.

ASA 5515 Security Plus
Cisco ASA Software Version 9.9(2)
Firepower Extensible Operating System Version 2.3(1.84)

ASDM Version: 7.9(2)
ASA Version: 9.9(2)

Encryption: 3DES-AES

[Vulnerability Link](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-asdm-rce-gqjShXW)

Comment: You should contact Cisco TAC. We have no way to fix bugs in the code, You need to see if there is an updated code version to fix it, or when there may be one released.

Comment: Do you actually use ASDM? If so, contact Cisco TAC for a software fix. If not (which should be the case for everyone because ASDM is garbage, imo), disable ASDM (via the command `no http server enable`) or delete the ASDM image off the disk (via the command `del flash:/asdm-792.bin`), or lock down ASDM access to only allow access from specific hosts/networks. Any of those options effectively mitigate the risk.

Comment: Also, you should move all management functions to a dedicated, tightly controlled VLAN, then these vulnerabilities become much less scary.

Comment: Do you guys know if the ASDM is part of the management VLAN in the ASA? I would just have to tighten access to that VLAN then correct?

Comment: @John There are no VLANs in an ASA (at least not on current models since the interfaces are all routed rather than switched, like they were on 5505 model units) unless you create them via sub-interfaces.

Comment: @john Bind all management services only to a dedicated interface connected to a secured VLAN. Use tight control (ACLs, firewall rules, separate authentication, ...) over access to that VLAN. (You can also use a tagged subinterface to a switch VLAN trunk but a dedicated link is somewhat better.)

Answer (score 4):

The way to fix or remove the vulnerability is to obtain a newer version of ASDM that does not contain the vulnerability.  You would have to get that from Cisco.

You can also apply other methods ("compensating controls") to limit the ability to exploit the vulnerability or reduce its impact if exploited.

One obvious method as @JesseP mentioned, is to simply not use ASDM.

Since the vulnerability is in the client loader or ASDM, not in the ASA itself, you have to protect the client, including all the vulnerabilities in the client operating system as well as the infrastructure between the client and the ASA.  An out-of-band solution would be one way of mitigating this vulnerability.

If your main goal is to prevent an audit finding, upgrading the ASDM software may be the easiest method.